# How to write $c$ when $c\mid pa$?

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number and $\gcd(p,a)=1$ for some natural number $a$. 
We also have $c\mid (p\cdot a)$
Can we say that $c=p\cdot d$ for some divisor $d$ of $a$?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, $5\mid 3\cdot 5$ but $5$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: $3|2 \cdot 3$ but there does not exist $d$ that divides 3 such that $3 = 2d$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $a$ coprime with $p$ and $c$ a divisor of $a$.